# html onload not running javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, onload

I'm writing a game in javascript, and I had the world generator running fine, but when I created a startup function to run multiple things at once, my code doesn't run at all anymore. Can anyone see my problem?

```
<head>
<title>Project Rust</title>
<!-- <link href="/YOUR_PATH/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" /> -->
<script src="Scripts/startup.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/drawmap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/maps.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/mapread.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/mainchar.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#BFE3FF" onload="startup()">
</body>
```

startup.js:
`startup(){
    alert("start");
    drawmap(Screen[0]);
    mainchar();
}`

Comment: Hi Aidan, I think you should write `function startup() {alert('start');}`

Comment: Are you sure the startup.js is being loaded? Which browser are you using?

Comment: you need to add the word `function` = `function startup(){alert("start"); drawmap(Screen[0]); mainchar();}`

Comment: @Jeroen This wasn't written in JSfiddle, I'm doing it in notepad++.

Comment: @AidanEdwards: No, but you could provide a JSFiddle for the people that want to help you.

Comment: @EH Now I feel stupid.. :P You got it.

Comment: @Aidan You can upload what you have written to jsfiddle, that way we can run it an see what's wrong

Comment: @Jeroen I have 5 diffrent .js files

Comment: That's not a problem, you can add as many as you want. But If I understand correctly you're problem has already been solved :)

Comment: @Joeron It has. Made me feel really stupid, too.

Comment: @Quentin I know, When I changed the title it wouldn't let me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the type to the script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/startup.js"></script>
```

Also, you need to use the `function` keyword to define a function in javascript:

```
function startup(){
  alert("start");
  drawmap(Screen[0]);
  mainchar();
}
```

If it's still now working, open your browser's javascript console and you should see the error.

Comment: HTML 5 makes the type attribute optional.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function startup(){
    alert("start"); drawmap(Screen[0]); mainchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the function declaration in your startup.js

You need `function startup(){ /*your code*/ }`